# Custom IWebProxy implementation, when using with HttpClient doesn't detect Credentials change?

Tags: c#, proxy, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to write a basic rotating proxy implementation for `HttpClient` via the `IWebProxy` interface, problem is when changing the `IWebProxy.Credentials` property inside `GetProxy` the request doesn't actually use the credentials set and therefore the proxy returns error 407:

```
namespace ProxyTestMin
{
    public record WebProxyEntry(Uri Uri, ICredentials Credentials);
    public class MyWebProxy : IWebProxy
    {
        private List<WebProxyEntry> _proxies;
        private int _position = 0;
        public MyWebProxy(List<WebProxyEntry> proxies) => _proxies = proxies;

        public ICredentials? Credentials { get; set; }
        public bool IsBypassed(Uri host) => false;
        public Uri? GetProxy(Uri destination)
        {
            _position++;
            _position %= _proxies.Count;
            Credentials = _proxies[_position].Credentials;
            return _proxies[_position].Uri;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static List<WebProxyEntry> proxies = new()
        {
            new(new("http://XX.XX.XX.XX:3128"), new NetworkCredential("user1", "pass1")),
            new(new("http://YY.YY.YY.YY:3128"), new NetworkCredential("user2", "pass2")),
        };

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { Proxy = new MyWebProxy(proxies) };
            using var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < proxies.Count; i++)
            {
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://api.ipify.org");
                Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}:" + await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I disable authentication on the proxy it works OK, and if I set the user/pass to be the same on all proxies and just set `Credentials` in the `MyWebProxy` constructor it also works fine. Unfortunately though I need to be able to have different credentials for each proxy, and it seems that if `Credentials` is set anywhere other than the constructor the `GetAsync` call uses the wrong credentials for the proxy.

Does anyone know if there's a way to workaround this *without* creating multiple HttpClientHandler/HttpClient instances?